# IronPython attribute is not callable

Tags: c#, attributes, decorator, asp.net-web-api2, ironpython

I have a problem with the following IronPython attribute (`RouteAttribute`):

```
import clr
import System
from System.Web.Http import HttpGetAttribute, ApiController, RouteAttribute


class DemoController(ApiController):

    @RouteAttribute("~/api/test")
    def test(self):
        return "Hallo Welt!"

class DemoControllerClr:

    def getType(self):
        return clr.GetClrType(DemoController)
```

If i create an instance of the DemoController-Class, i always get the error-message: `RouteAttribute is not callable`. I do not create an instance of `DemoController` on my own, the asp.net web api 2 tries to do this.

Maybe some one has some experiances with attributes in IronPython.

**EDIT**

My aim is, to mix C# and IronPython API-Controller. I register the controller like this (The c# ones works):

```
controller = new Dictionary<string, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor>();

controller.Add("General", new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor(config, "General", typeof(Controller.GeneralController)));

foreach (DBScript script in dbContext.LoadData<DBScript>(optWherePart: "ScriptContentType = 1"))
{ 
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

    var sc = ScriptManager.Singleton.CreateScript(script.ScriptName, ScriptLanguage.IronPython);

    var clrInst = sc.GetClassInstance(script.ScriptName + "Clr");

    controller.Add(script.ScriptName.Replace("Controller", ""), new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor(config,
        script.ScriptName.Replace("Controller", ""), clrInst.getType()));
}
```

**EDIT2**

I'm using the newest release of IronPython (2.7.5).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not work, bevause the dependency injection mechanism does not work together with ironpython, because of the dlr. So just don't work.